# How to use radio buttons and checkboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html><!--start of html file-->
<head><!--start of head-->

</head><!--end of head-->
<script type = "text/javascript" ><!--Start of javascript-->
function checkData()/*function to check data*/
{
    function checkDay()
    {
    var car;
    var extras;
    for (i=0; i<document.durationForm.length;i++)
    {
        if(document.durationForm[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("durationForm[i]");
            alert(durationForm[i]);
        }
    }
    }//end of checkDay()
    /*for (i=0; i<document.carForm.length;i++)
    {
        if(document.carForm[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("carForm");
        }
    }*/
    /*alert("You got" + cartype + rbutton + extras);*/


}   
function hello()
{
    alert("hi");
}
</script><!-- end of script-->




<body><!--start of body-->

    <table border = "1" align = "center"><!--start of table-->
        <tr><!-- start table row-->
            <td><b>DURATION<br/>
            <!-- start duration table column-->
                <form name= "durationForm">
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" id= "One Day" value="One Day" checked="checked">One Day <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" id= "Weekend"value="Weekend">Weekend                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="duration" id= "Weekly" value="Weekly">Weekly                      <br></b>
                </form>
            </td>

            <td><b>VEHICLE TYPE</b><br/>
            <!-- start Vehicle type table column-->
                <form name = "carForm">
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="Compact Car" checked="checked">Compact Car <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="Midsize">Midsize <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="Fullsized">Fullsized <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="Van">Van <br>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end table row-->
        <tr><!-- start table row-->
            <td colspan  = "2" align = "center"><b>EXTRA</b><br/>
            <!-- start Extras table column-->
                <table><!--check box table-->
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type= "checkbox" name = "A/C"/> A/C(+$10) </td>
                        <td><input type= "checkbox" name = "Working Brakes"/> Working Brakes(+$100)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type= "checkbox" name = "Cruise Control"/>Cruise Control (+$20) </td>
                        <td><input type= "checkbox" name = "Baby Seat"/> Baby Seat(+$30) </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!--end of check box table-->
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end table row-->
        <tr><!-- start table row-->
            <td colspan  = "2" align = "center">
                <form name = "myForm">
                    <input type = "button" value = "Estimated Cost" onClick="checkData();">
                    <!-- start Estimated Cost button table column-->
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end table row-->
    </table><!-- end table-->
</body><!-- end body-->
</html><!-- html file-->
```

I'm kinda new to HTML and Javascript. I'm not really sure whether the problem was in the scripting of the function checkData() or the radio buttons and checkboxes if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I reproduced this page here and see no errors.

Comment: Really, no problem with function inside of a function?

Comment: Yeah the buttons don't seem to work. try the Estimated Cost button. it was suppose to call the check Data which was suppose to get the 3 things inside the table and put it inside the commented alert.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `document.getElementById("durationForm[i]");`

Your browser tries to find an element with that exact ID, not the `i`th child of the durationForm. You must iterate over the child nodes of durationForm. Using something like jQuery will also make your life much easier as you try to traverse children, etc..

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will get get right on that when the time allows.

Answer (score 0):

First avoid to use functions inside functions if you are a Javascript begginer, that kind of usage is more associate to javascript "classes".

Well, to solve your problem, I would recoment to set an ID for your forms to access it by the Web Standard getElementById document function.

Assuming that the your forms now have an id:

Html:

```
 <form name= "durationForm" id="durationForm">
```

Javascript:

```
function checkData() 
{
    var frmDuration = document.getElementById('durationForm');
    checkForm(frmDuration);
}

function checkForm(frmTarget)
{
    for (i=0; i<frmTarget.length;i++) 
    {
        if (frmTarget.elements[i].type == 'CHECKBOX') 
        {
            alert(frmTarget.elements[i].value);
        }
    }

}
```

With that in mind you could also check for the multiple forms, like so:

```
function checkDataAll() 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) 
        checkForm(document.forms[i]);
}
```

Comment: its a paramater that the checkForm expect to receive. The checkData passes that in the call to 'checkForm'